# How can "the number of times" be abbreviated?

Tags: proper-nouns

> This circuit reduces the number of times data is sampled.

I named the circuit as follows:

> A sampling number reducing circuit

I think "sampling frequency reducing circuit" may be better but too technical. I am afraid that "sampling number" is misinterpreted as the order of sampled data". If the context is clear, is "sampling number reducing circuit" acceptable?

Comment: My idea: "Data sampling interval reduction circuit."

Comment: In such cases, tell the full term and come up with an acronym. Say, in your case: SNRC or in @user3169's case: DSIRC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might simply say

> This *data sampling* circuit reduces the number of times data is sampled.
>
> A *data sampling* circuit

Using "***sampling***" implies that that it is not "**continuous***".

Comment: I gave up and decided to use "frequency".